# Длительное ожидание при междоменных http запросах

Tags: http, микросервисы

Есть несколько поддоменов. Везде symfony

1. Фронт dev.mydomain.ru
2. Авторизация (jwt токен) dev-auth.mydomain.ru
3. API (Swagger) dev-api.mydomain.ru

Есть еще, но это не существенно

Фронт делает http запросы в API некоторые с токеном, некоторые без.
Но.
Когда я делаю запрос без токена постманом - ответ прилетает через 500-800 миллисекунд
Если запрос отправляется с фронта, тот же замый запрос может занимать секунд 6 или больше.
Лог фронта:

**Запрос**

[2021-08-31T08:41:42.635987+00:00] http_client.INFO: Request: "GET [https://dev-api.mydomain.ru/classifiers/aircraft/"](https://dev-api.mydomain.ru/classifiers/aircraft/%22) [] []

**Ответ**
[2021-08-31T08:41:47.291996+00:00] http_client.INFO: Response: "200 [https://dev-api.mydomain.ru/classifiers/aircraft/"](https://dev-api.mydomain.ru/classifiers/aircraft/%22) [] []

Во вкладке Network админской консоли хрома это время идёт как Waiting TTFB

Апач, php 7.7

**В какую сторону копать?**

[image: Скрин админской консоли хрома при междоменном запросе]

Comment: Waiting TTFB это просто ожидание ответа, дебажить надо и/или на серваке метрики чекать чтоб посмотреть что грузит так долго.. А зачем для авторизации отдельный url?

Comment: Отдельный урл отдаёт jwt. Если стучатьтся с прилаги или еще откуда - лучше отдельный

Comment: Что такое чекать метрики? По каким словам погуглить?